# Ctrl + F5 on a Cromebook

Tags: visual-studio, chromebook

I am working with my `Visual Studio` from a Chromebook...

In order to run the non-debug mode I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

How to do it on a Chromebook, Ctrl+Switcher does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

Control + Search + Window Switcher button (i.e. fifth key from left) should work.  If not, you can turn on treating the top row as function keys in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is right, you need to use <kbd>Search</kbd> to access the function keys. [Here](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Media_keys_and_default_keybindings) are some other useful shortcuts and further explanation from GalliumOS/Crouton that should work on ChromeOS like <kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>. I wasn't able to find the corresponding page at support.google.com.